# Download from Google Drive with a WebView using DownloadManager

Tags: android, webview, download

In my Android `WebView` app, when I'm downloading a file with a name in Chinese, Arabic or Russian from Google Drive, the file will be downloaded with a name like this:

```
___________ ____.pdf
```

[image]

if some one have solution for that problem. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
val fileName =
        URLDecoder
            .decode(
                contentDisposition
                    .toString()
                    .substringAfter("UTF-8''"), "utf-8"
            )
```

Answer (score 0):

+17 is the number of characters that you want to remove before file name(which are filename*=UTF-8")

```
final String filename = (contentDisposition.substring(contentDisposition.lastIndexOf("filename*=UTF-8")+17));
```